# Added a service connection to the Azure Devops project to connect to App Config but App config doesn't show the Service connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-app-configuration

Added a service connection to the Azure Devops project to connect to App Config but App config doesn't show the Service connection. I'm getting a not authorized when try to connect to App Config from Azure Devops pipeline.

> ##[error]Access to 'https://test-app-configs.azconfig.io/kv?key=*&label=%00&api-version=1.0' was denied. Please ensure the required role assignment is made for the identity running this task.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with the following things:

1. Check whether your account has the permissions to access Azure App Configuration under the specified Azure subscription and the App Configuration resource. If you do not have the permissions, you may need to contact the administrators in the Azure AD to grant you the access.
2. How did you create the ARM connection (Azure Resource Manager service connection)? **`Automatic`** type or **`Manual`** type?
   If you create the ARM connection using **`Manual`** type with a service principal, make sure you have assigned the required role to this service principal so that you can use it to access the App Configuration.

For more details, you can reference the following documents:

- [Push settings to App Configuration with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/push-kv-devops-pipeline)
- [Pull settings to App Configuration with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/pull-key-value-devops-pipeline)